# RunTime Error: Vector Subscript Out of Range: Checking Empty Set

Tags: c++, set

During debugging of my Node struct I came across a runtime error "Vector Subscript out of Range". I am using an if statement to test to see if my set `parents` is empty or not to determine whether or not its children are "usable". The error is thrown when it checks a `node` that has an empty `parents` set.

isUsable is located within the Node struct:

```
bool isUsable() {
        if (parents.size() == 0) //<-- Error here
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
```

Call from main:

```
for (int c = 0; c < nodes.size(); c++) {
        if (!nodes[c]->isUsable()) {
            nodes[c]->setParent(*nodes[-1]);
        }
    }
```

Relevant declarations:

```
vector<Node*> nodes;
set<Node*> parents;
```

I have tried using:

```
parents.size() == 0
!parents.empty()
parents.begin() == parents.end()
```

All return the same error. How could I fix this problem or is there another way I can check to see if a vector is empty?

Comment: `nodes[-1]` Huh?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik does that not return the last element of a list?

Comment: No it does not. It exhibits undefined behavior by way of accessing an index out of bounds. C++ is not Python. You probably want `nodes.back()`

Comment: That fixed it. I've been very used to using the -1 as a means of reaching the end of a list. Thank you, @IgorTandetnik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Negative indexing for an array is allowed with some restrictions.

For example:

```
std::vector<int> vectInt = {12, 23, 34, 45};
int x = vectInt [-1]; // invalid; out of range
```

But this would be okay:

```
std::vector<int> vectInt = {12, 23, 34, 45};
int* p = &vectInt[1];

int x = p[-1]; // valid:  accesses arr[0]
```

From CPP standard working draft (N4713):

> **11.3.4 Arrays [dcl.array]**
>   ...
>   Note: *Except where it has been declared for a class*, the subscript operator [] is interpreted in such a way that E1[E2] is identical to *((E1)+(E2)). Because of the conversion rules that apply to +, if E1 is an array and E2 an integer, then E1[E2] refers to the E2-th member of E1. Therefore, despite its asymmetric appearance, subscripting is a commutative operation. —end note ]

The subscript operator `[]` is defined for `vector`. Since `vector` class has a `back` function defined which accesses the last element, you should be using that.